# Nuances between "столь/настолько/так (твёрдо) уверен"

Tags: словоупотребление, выбор-слова

To express the idea of:

> How come you're **so**[**that much** / **this much** / **to this extent**] sure of it?

The following phrasings all seem to be saying more or less the same thing:

> Почему ты в нем **столь** / **настолько** / **так** уверен?

But I wonder if and how they are nuanced? Also, if I use any of these words with `твёрдо` (like in `столь/настолько/так твёрдо уверен) - will it make a difference?

Comment: Hi. You can try to edit the question so that it would be clear what you are asking. Translations per se are off-topic. If you want to ask what's the difference between `твёрдо`, `столь` and `настолько` - that's a completely different thing.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what my question is all about: "Nuances[Difference in meaning] between", "I wonder if and how they are nuanced[differ in meaning]". And as the "usage" tag indicates, it's not at all about translation. I'm afraid I fail to see how my wording can be edited otherwise... I think it's clear enough as is... @shabunc

Comment: np, I can edit it for you so that you can see what I mean.

Comment: "Настолько" is a little bit more doubtful than "так". "Why are you so sure about it? (you shouldn't be)"  vs "Why are you so sure about it? (I just don't know, please explain)".

Answer (score 3):

**Почему ты в нём столь уверен?** Sounds quite archaic to be honest, or at least very formal.

**Почему ты в нём настолько уверен?** and **Почему ты в нём так уверен?** are conveying the same meaning without noticeable difference in nuances.

Adding **твёрдо** doesn't change anything really.

Comment: +1 for mentioning that `столь` is actually archaic